# Ajax calls duplicate in jQuery loop

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, popover

The function creates a popover (bootstrap)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //loop as there are pages with more than one popover
    $('.pop').each(function() {
        var $elem = $(this);
        $elem.popover(param); //triggers popover                    
        $elem.on('click', '.add_to_top', function() {                                          
            top_modal.modal('show');   //opens modal where form is
            //inside the modal is a form
            $(top_modal).on('click', '.add_top_submit', function() {
               //this submits a form where the ajax call is
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The issue is that if for example, the submit form button is clicked and throws an error, then resubmitted the ajax requests is sent twice. Everytime .add_top_submit is clicked on a modal triggered by a different popover, the ajax call is made once more.

If there are more than one popover on the page and that the modal is triggered from two different popovers, the ajax requests also goes through multiple times.

**Is there a way to "reset" `on()` so it is always clicked as if it was for the first time?**

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to "reset" on() so it is always clicked as if it was for the first time?

You can use off() and then on() to reset the event handlers.
http://api.jquery.com/off/

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to fix it. At the end of the function triggering the final form, I added this:

```
                    top_modal.die(); //unbinds all events
                    top_modal.on('click'); //rebind click in case form is submitted again
```

Comment: @TJ What's an alternative to live()?

Comment: live is  deprecated from `1.7` onwards and removed from `1.9+`... From `1.7` onwards use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)